# How to get all the deleted Knowledge Article in Salesforce

Tags: apex, soql, knowledge, articles, recycle-bin

I already tried below query:

```
SELECT Id, KnowledgeArticleId, 
                             Title, PublishStatus, Isdeleted 
                             FROM Help_Center__kav WHERE 
                             language = 'en_US' 
                             AND publishStatus = 'Draft' 
                             AND isdeleted = true
                             ALL ROWS
```

and

```
SELECT Id, KnowledgeArticleId, 
                             Title, PublishStatus, Isdeleted 
                             FROM Help_Center__kav WHERE 
                             language = 'en_US' 
                             AND publishStatus = 'Online' 
                             AND isdeleted = true
                             ALL ROWS
```

and

```
SELECT Id, KnowledgeArticleId, 
                             Title, PublishStatus, Isdeleted 
                             FROM Help_Center__kav WHERE 
                             language = 'en_US' 
                             AND publishStatus = 'Archived' 
                             AND isdeleted = true
                             ALL ROWS
```

But I get no record. Even though I see the record in the recycle bin at the left sidebar on the Home page. 

Can anyone tell me how to select the knowledge article record that already deleted and moved in Salesforce recycle bin?

Answer (score 3):

This is really weird, maybe salesforce is storing deleted article somewhere else.

With following query, it shows the deleted `KnowledgeArticle`'s:

```
SELECT Id, ArticleNumber, ArchivedById, ArchivedDate 
    FROM 
    KnowledgeArticle 
    WHERE IsDeleted = true
    ALL ROWS
```